# Is it possible to crawl a website for scripts and also track the successive scripts loaded by them using Puppeteer

Tags: web-scraping, scripting, phantomjs, puppeteer

I would like to know if there is a possibility to crawl for scripts loaded in a page and then find the linking between those scripts.

Comment: How are the successive scripts loaded? `$.getScript()`? `document.createElement('script')`?

Comment: Yea, I was thinking of something similar.
But then I came across an example in puppeteer by Eric(https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/puppeteer-examples) which crawls for links. But getting few errors in it (crawl.json not gettig created).

In the project which I'm doing, I would like to get scripts if they are dynamically loaded--> like an iframe which can also load scripts

Comment: @GrantMiller I used  document.querySelectorAll('script[src]'); to get the scripts with sources.
My challenge is how to get links between these scripts.
When looking at the Network tab in Chrome Dev tools, we can hover through and get the initiators.
I am trying to get the same via a code.

Comment: Hi @GrantMiller, I had seen another post of your's stating how the initiator details can be obtained. Thanks for the code.
I had tried it but I'm not getting the initiator url's for few request though there is a url mentioned in the network tab.